# Anchor category - display only price/category filter in layered navigation

Tags: magento2

I'll explain you what am I trying to achieve. Basically I am setting up a shop for a customer. We've got categories like:
-**Clothes**:

- pants
- tshirts

We want products from subcategories (pants, tshirts) to be displayed in parent category (Clothes) too. However products are linked only to subcategories. That is why we enabled Anchor in Clothes category. Everything is okay now but we've got big amount of filters available in Clothes category. The thing is: in parent category I want only 2 filters to be displayed (Category, Price). Other filters should be only visible in categories without childs.
So what I already achieved is hiding all filters in specified category (like Clothes) by adding

**referenceContainer name="catalog.leftnav" remove="true"**

to Layout Update XML. Is there any way to render only Price and Category filter by using xml? Or any other ideas how can I achieve this ?